# Adding in application Google Account using AccountManager

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-signin

I'm trying to add functionality in my application, that add a google account to Android Account Manager, by use of method
    `mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseApplicationContext());`
 `Account account = new Account("sample.account", "com.google");`
        `ac.addAccountExplicitly(account, "password", null);`
But it indicates an exception

> java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10117 is different than the
>   authenticato r's uid

Is it possible to add account in application code (being more precisely logging to already existing google account)? Which method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the same UID as the account type but you can't sign your app with the package (it get's translated into the UID) "com.google".

You can get the Accounts available using:

```
manager.getAccountsByType("com.google"); // returns array
```

or with API level 14 you can call:

```
AccountManager.newChooseAccountsIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
```

If you want it on earlier versions you can get the source code and implement the same mechanics in your project.

The only option to add a Google account would be to get the intents that are sent when the login Activity is sent and try to send the same intent to ask the user to input the account. Once in you can get the details with the method I've mentioned.